# Group Expression Relating to Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a simple question about cosets that is evading me if anybody can provide a hand. I don't think the title informs the question much so if anybody can rephrase the title for me that would be appreciated.

### Question

Is it true that for any subgroup $H$ of a finite group $G$, $\exists x \in G$ such that $G = \bigcup\limits_{i=0}^{|H|-1}x^iH$?

Comment: What if $H=\{e\}$?

Comment: Should it be $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i = 0}^{|G|/|H| - 1}$ instead?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Then G would have to contain a generator and thus be cyclic and not all finite groups are cyclic so $H=\{e\}$ is a counterexample?

Comment: @Arthur: The source uses $|H|-1$ but it could be a typo I suppose.

Comment: Exactly! @Dohleman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not true. Let $G$ be a non-trivial finite group and let $H=\{e_G\}$. Then your assertion means that, for some $x\in G$, $G=e_G\{e_G\}=\{e_G\}$.

Comment: Well,here order of $H=1$. So it will imply that $G=H $.

Comment: Actually, it does. It means that $G=e_G\{e_G\}=\{e_G\}$. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: Yep, I realised it only after posting the comment.

Answer (score 3):

If the subgroup $H$ happens to be normal (and assuming that the exponent $i$ should range from $0$ to $|G|/|H| - 1$ instead, which is the most number if we are just counting the number of elements), then what you are asking is equivalent to the quotient group $G/H$ being cyclic. And this is just not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to construct a counterexample.

We consider the group of symmetries of a square [$D_8$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dihedral_group:D8). It contains $8$ elements and it is non commutative.

The [Center](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Center_of_dihedral_group:D8) of the group is $Z(D_8)=Z=\{e, a^2\}=H$. The quotient group $G/Z$ exists, $G=D_8$.

Supposing that there does exist a $y \in G$, such that, [assuming $x^0= e, \forall x \in G$ ], $G=D_8 = \displaystyle\bigcup_{i=0}^{|H|-1}{y^iH} \ \ ... (a)$. But, evidently for any $y \in G$, $|yH|=2$.

$|H|-1=2-1=1$. So, $|\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=0}^{|H|-1}{y^iH}| \leq 4 < |D_8|$.

Therefore, no $y \in D_8$ can satisfy the equality $(a)$.

**Again, taking into consideration the possibility of a typo** [ $\frac{|G|}{|H|}-1$ instead of $|H|-1$]:

Notice that there are only two elements of order $4$ which are $a$ and $a^3$.

Now, taking the union $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=0}^{\frac{|G|}{|H|}-1}{a^iH}=\{e, a^2\} \cup \{a, a^3 \} \cup \{a^2, e\} \cup \{a^3, a\}=\{e, a^2\} \cup \{a, a^3 \}$.

The case is identical for $a^3$.

Either way, the claim is false.

Comment: The links have been mentioned to avoid any notational confusion that might arise.